# Why is fill3DRect not working correctly on other computers besides my own?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-2d, paintcomponent

I am working on a visual sorting algorithm project and I am drawing them in a JPanel:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        g.fill3DRect(i * barWidth, height, barWidth, -array[i], true);
    }
    g.dispose();
}
```

I compiled my program and ran the jar on my Windows 7 computer and I get the bars drawn correctly:

[image: good]

I tested this on another Windows 7 computer and a Mac and it drew the bars incorrectly:

[image: bad]

Why is this happening? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: As an aside, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Comment: What is the incorrection? Are the bars gray? Are thay not at same height/width ratio? Filling whole screen with that color?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. Also consider [tag:jfreechart].

Answer (score 3):

```
g.dispose();
```

Only call `dispose()` on graphics instances that your code creates.  This one is supplied by the JRE.

Comment: And don't forget to change the override from `paint()` to `paintComponent()`